# gcc options in netbeans 8.0

Tags: c++, gcc, netbeans, netbeans-8

I'm trying to debug a c++ project (existing code) in Netbeans.

I can run the code fine by hitting the `Run` button, but debugging isn't working for some reason. I've seen a lot of suggestions telling that the `-g` flag needs  to be added to the `gcc` compiler options in Netbeans.

From what I understand this used to be done through the *Aditional options" field in the project properties. But this field doesn't exist anymore in Netbeans 8.

Where can I add the `-g` flag to the `gcc` compiler options in Netbeans 8?

Comment: Do you have makefile in your project directory?

Comment: @HEKTO Yes the project has a (auto generated) make file

Comment: I don't understand - you said this is "Project with Existing Sources". This type of project can't have auto-generated makefile

Comment: @HEKTO Netbeans does seem to do something with it. I can tell by the last *Access date*. The `MakeFile` isn't there when I download the Sources.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a normal `C++ Application` project, then your NetBeans pulldown menu (to the left of the `Build Project` button - an icon with hammer) should have at least three lines - `Debug`, `Release` and `Customize`. Choose the `Debug` configuration to build the project, then the -g option will be added automatically.